# Phenylalanine reduction to phenylalaninol

Tags: redox

Since phenylalanine is reduced to phenylalaninol in 16-18 hours under reflux with sodium borohydride and sulfuric acid in dry tetrahydrofuran. My question is, to reduce $\pu{100g}$ of phenylalanine, how much sodium borohydride and sulfuric acid are needed?

Also, what is the quantity of dry THF used in the reflux? After the reflux can I remove the sodium borohydride with a filtration, as well as the THF/sulfuric acid/phenylalanine batch that is neutralised with NaOH? I also want to extract the phenylalaninol with toluene.

Comment: How is there sodium borohydride plus sulfuric acid?  I thought sodium borohydride breaks down with strong acid.

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with the Sodium Borohydride/sulfuric acid procedure, however this paper https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo000242h contains a procedure with 2eq LiBH4 and 4eq TMSiCl in THF for the reduction you want. Based on this method you will need 600ml THF.

There is also this paper that uses NaBH4 and NiCl2 in water and claims an 83% yield for the redution of Phenylalanine.  http://journals.tubitak.gov.tr/chem/issues/kim-99-23-2/kim-23-2-2-98058.pdf